# Access values in JTextfield from another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textfield

Can someone check my code if there is something wrong because when I call the getter method it displays nothing. Somehow it does not store the inputs from the text field that I am trying to use.

---

here are some of codes:

Login Button from class A

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         System.out.println("1"+getuser());
    try {

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/devweb", "root", "123456");
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select User,pwd from account");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
         name = user.getText();
        String pwd = jTextField2.getText();

        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getString("User").equals(name) && rs.getString("pwd").equals(pwd)) {
                result now = new result();
                now.res();
                dispose();
                 System.out.println("2"+getuser());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

---

Then this the view button from class B:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    log qwe=new log();
    jTextField1.setText(qwe.getuser());
    System.out.println(qwe.getuser());//when I print this it just says null
}
```

note: at this point I just want to see if it will be able to get the input from the log in page that is why what my code does is just print the inputted user name.

Comment: Please see **Edit 2** in my answer regarding your recent edits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's something wrong: your use of *static*. Getter methods should be instance methods and so there should be no statics involved.

The other issue I often see with this sort of code is *when* are you trying to extract the text? Is it event driven and only called *after* text has been added to the JTextField? Or do you try to call this method on program start-up when the user hasn't had a chance to enter text yet? It's hard to say if this affects you though as we only have a limited view of your code and problem.

Another issue that is not uncommon is trying to extract information from a shadow object and not the actual object that is currently being displayed. Your second code window suggests that this may be an issue since you create a log object immediately before trying to extract information from it. This could be a second log object and could be not displayed at all.

To see if any of these issues effect you or if you need more or deeper advice, you may wish to show more code.

**Edit 2**
Regarding your recent edit, your code could work if log is a modal dialog, but still tough to say as your added code gives us *some* information but still not enough. Don't lose heart as there is an art to deciding what is not enough information/code to post here vs enough information vs. too much information. You will get better at this with practice.

Comment: yes i am trying to extract the text. What my program is supposed to do is the user will log in and after logging in the details of his account will show up. So that is why I am trying to extract the username so that that will be the one I will be using to verify which profile to show from the database

Comment: @user1006328: to help you further, I think that we'll need to see more.